# Delete a file in use by another process in vb.net / framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net, process, delete-file

I have a program that watches if there is a file with a certain name, in a certain directory.
the FileStream is created with the sequent command:

`fs = File.Open(PathK, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)`

After half an hour, the program closes, disposes and kills the text file and then shuts down itself, calling for another program to create another process of itself and closes the old one.

Sometimes this doesn't happen though. The file can't be removed and it causes an error. 
After that the program closes itself and continues with its restart routine. but when it starts itself, it checks if there is that specific file, and there it is, because it couldn't kill it. Now, i can do `File.OpenRead` on that file, so the old filestream of the old process is not running, so it means the old one process is shut down. But I still can't kill it!

this is the starting code:

```
Private Sub Verifica_PID_Aperti()
    Dim Tentativi As Integer = 0

    PidAlreadyOpen = 0


    'file exist ?
    If File.Exists(PathK) = True Then

        Try
            'can i read it?
            File.OpenRead(PathK)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'if it's locked than there is another PID active right now, stop this process
            Settaggi.lStop = 1
            PidAlreadyOpen = 1
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        'not locked? than it's a bug and the file is still open, try to delete
        While (Tentativi < 1000)

            Try
                File.Delete(PathK)
                Tentativi = 1000

            Catch ex As Exception
                Tentativi = Tentativi + 1
            End Try
        End While

        'is him still alive?
        If File.Exists(PathK) Then
            'if yes, there is an error, sand a mail and close yourself
            Dim pf As New Send_Mail
            pf.Invio_Mail_Automatico_EDP(999, "ERRORECHIUSURA", Err.Description & " - " & PathK, "", Settaggi.lPID)
            pf = Nothing
            Settaggi.lStop = 1
            PidAlreadyOpen = 1
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'ok, if it does not exists anymore, create another one
            fs = File.Open(PathK, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
        End If
    Else
        'no file ? than create it
        fs = File.Open(PathK, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    End If

End Sub
```

and here it's the code for the restart procedure:

```
    If PidAlreadyOpen = 0 Then
        'close and clean

        fs.Close()
        fs.Dispose()

    End If

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    Dim Chiusura As Integer = 0

    While Chiusura < 1000
        Try
            'try to delete

            File.Delete(PathK)

            If TimeToReboot = 1 Then
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, "/noservice /release /PID:" & Settaggi.lPID)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

            Chiusura = Chiusura + 1
            ' not deleted ? send an email, and don't stop yourself
            If Chiusura = 999 Then
                Dim pf As New Send_Mail
                pf.Invio_Mail_Automatico_EDP(999, "ERRORECHIUSURA", Err.Description & " - " & PathK, "", Settaggi.lPID)
                pf = Nothing
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        End Try
        'deleted? than stop the loop
        If Not File.Exists(PathK) Then
            Chiusura = 1000
        End If

    End While

    Me.Close()
```

how do you think should i resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's much you can do here. I had similar issues in the past and found that, while it's not possible to delete the file, it is possible to rename the file. Depending on the situation, you can rename the file and open a new file with that name. You'll also need to check, later in the process, if the renamed file is still used and delete it.